# Display value from dictionary in listview instead of abbreviation

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` where I display a collection of entities.

One of these columns contains an abbreviation, and I would like to display another text.
I have both the abbreviation and the 'display'-string in a dictionary.

Is there any way I can display the 'display'-string from the dictionary instead of the abbreviation, without changing the entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a value `Converter`, e.g:

**View**

```
<ListView.View>  
   <GridView>  
       <GridViewColumn Header="Abbreviation">  
            <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>  
                <Binding Path="Abv" Converter="{StaticResource abvConverter}"/>  
            </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>  
        </GridViewColumn>  
    </GridView>  
</ListView.View>
```

**Value Converter**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]  
public class AbbreviationConverter : IValueConverter  
{  
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
        // error checking
        return myDictionaryInstance[value.ToString()];
    }  

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
        ...  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared the dictionary like this in the view model
private Dictionary m_DictRows;

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> DictRows
    {
        get { return m_DictRows; }
        set { m_DictRows = value; }
    }
```

then in the xaml just need to bind in the below manner:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DictRows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Style="{DynamicResource txtID}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```